# Automate A Process on a Webpage

Tags: php

I have a webpage. There is an option to select file from the computer and then there is a submit button. 
File will be same on each upload. I just need to select the file from my computer (location will be the same everytime) and then click on submit button.

Is there any way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless you don't have your page in your own computer. PHP cannot access user's local files, and not even javascript. All because of security. You have always select the file by your own hands, any code could not access your local files. But if the file is same every time, you can save it to your web server and use it.

Edit

HTML:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Insert file</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP(upload.php):

```
<?php 
   $path = "upload/"; // uploads folder
   $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 

   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
     echo "File ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " uploaded.";
   } else{
     echo "Error, please try again.";
   }

?>
```

Comment: I have myfile.zip if i upload it to my website then what code i need to write?

Comment: Umm.. do you want to save it to your website?

Comment: I added upload example but it's not very secure. You can find better code to searching the net.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if that's the case, the HTTP POST submission will be the same each time. You can use any language of choice to send the POST submission over and over. There's also GUI tools to do this, namely [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), you could watch the post submission, and then select it, and hold SHIFT + R to keep reissuing the request.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't here to write the code for you, but we'll point you to the necessary resources to do it yourself, what language do you wanna do it in? PHP?

Comment: Yes I have very little knowledge of php and I wont be able to do by myself.